# Div with same height as width and "not simple" content in it

Tags: html, css

I created `<div>` with `height` same as the `width`, but now I have a problem with inner content.

Every example has a simple text in `div` like here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GYNXwr

`HTML`:

```
<div>
  <div class="center">TITLE </br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor porro animi iste quaerat corporis perferendis et!</div>
</div>
```

`CSS`:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  width: 20%;
  padding-top: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I want to split the TITLE from TEXT with some tags, but I want them to stay in center position. I need that because I want to show text only on hover, so I need somehow to hide it.

I had thought to put the title in `<h>` tag and text in `<p>` tag, and that to set visibility to hidden for `<p>` tag until hover. But when I do that, the title goes `left` and text `right`, and I can't get title above text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `flex-direction:column` and `justify-content: center`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

div.parent {
  position: relative;
  background: orange;
  width: 30%;
  padding-top: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

p {
  display: none;
}

.center:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center">
    <h1>TITLE</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor porro animi iste quaerat corporis perferendis et!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, i used `display: flex` on the container to mantain all the content in center position.
I added for you tags too :)

```css
div.simple-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 250px;
  background-color: orange;
}

div.simple-text ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

div.simple-text ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 6px;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

div.simple-text p {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

div.simple-text:hover p {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="simple-text">
  <h3>TITLE</h3>
  <ul>
    <li class="simple-tag">lorem</li>
    <li class="simple-tag">ipsum</li>
  </ul>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor porro animi iste quaerat corporis perferendis et!
  </p>
</div>
```